# Condition action in Logic App shows as Cancelled but evaluates fine

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

When there is a failure on an HTTP action, then all the conditions in my Logic App are shown as 'Cancelled' but they actually evaluate fine, and the Logic App completes successfully. It seems like it's just a matter of wrong display?

Has anyone encountered this?

This is what I see on the UI, and this is the case for all Conditions in my Logic App: [ConditionShownAsCancelled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGtwd.png)

Thank you in advance,
Tony

Comment: Did you find a solutions to this?

Answer (score -1):

If you want the logic app to terminate after the previous action is canceled, you need to add a scope to your logic app with pipline actions in the scope.  Then you can evaluate if the scope was successful or not.  See the documentation on scopes here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-control-flow-run-steps-group-scopes

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response Ken. Using a scope in my case does not seem relevant, considering the problem at hand. The actual problem is that my Condition actions have got a 'Cancelled' status when my HTTP task fails. Despite the fact they have a 'Cancelled' status though, they do evaluate and the Logic App runs successfully. Did I misunderstand maybe how using scope would solve this issue?

Comment: @AntoniosGeorgiadis I am seeing similar behavior in my logic apps, not sure why, did you fine what was causing this?

Comment: I'm having exactly same situation, any solution?