Azure Logic App: How to evaluate HTTP canceled in an condition
I have an Azure Logic App (Standard Tier) which sends data from a blob storage to an HTTP endpoint. The Logic App itself is triggered by an event, when a blob is stored on the storage account. Sometimes the HTTP endpoint throws an error or is too busy, so that the workflow step is canceled.
Therefor, to prevent data loss I implemented a condition, so that every time I get a status code which is not 200, the file will be transferred to an error storage account so that it can be processed later. For an error code like 400 or 401 it is working.
But in the case, that the workflow step is canceled, my condition does not work, and the file is marked as processed.

Code of the condition:
    {
  "type": "If",
  "expression": {
    "and": [
      {
        "equals": [
          "@variables('MasStatusCode')",
          "200"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "actions": {},
  "else": {
    "actions": {
      "Upload_blob_to_error_storage": {
        "type": "ServiceProvider",
        "inputs": {
          "parameters": {
            "containerName": "error",
            "blobName": "@concat('error/',variables('BlobName'))",
            "content": "@body('Read_blob_content')?['content']"
          },
          "serviceProviderConfiguration": {
            "connectionName": "AzureBlob-3",
            "operationId": "uploadBlob",
            "serviceProviderId": "/serviceProviders/AzureBlob"
          }
        }
      },
      "MAS_Log_to_Error": {
        "type": "ApiConnection",
        "inputs": {
          "host": {
            "connection": {
              "referenceName": "azureloganalyticsdatacollector"
            }
          },
          "method": "post",
          "body": "{\n\t\"fileName\": \"@{variables('TargetFileName')}\",\n\t\"direction\": \"FromKi\",\n\t\"Error\": \"MAS Upload: @{outputs('HTTP_Call_to_MAS')?['statusCode']}\",\n \"Message\": \"File moved to error container\"\n}",
          "headers": {
            "Log-Type": "KiError"
          },
          "path": "/api/logs"
        },
        "runAfter": {
          "Upload_blob_to_error_storage": [
            "SUCCEEDED"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "runAfter": {
    "Set_variable_MasStatusCode": [
      "SUCCEEDED",
      "TIMEDOUT",
      "SKIPPED",
      "FAILED"
    ]
  }
}

EDIT 22.05.2024
I can't find in the workflow runs, only in the error logs:

How can I catch this "canceled" event?

You don't really need to maintain the MasStatusCode variable and check if it equals 200. Neither do you need the Condition Upload MAS action.
The HTTP Call to MAS action can either fail (e.g. when 400 or 401 is returned, among other scenarios) or succeed (when 200 is returned). Or time out.
The general recommendation is to Manage the "run after" behavior.
You can do it by creating 2 parallel branches after the HTTP Call to MAS, like this:

Scope Success will run only when HTTP Call to MAS succeeds:

Scope Error will run only when HTTP Call to MAS times out or fails:

Of course, if someone manually cancels the workflow before it's reached any of the scopes, the file will not be transferred to the error storage account. But in this scenario nothing can be done apart from redesigning the solution - e.g. one workflow to send a message with details of the blob to a Service Bus queue, and another workflow to process messages from the Service Bus queue - then nothing will ever be lost.

Thanks, I will consider using scopes, but: The step "Call to MAS" is canceled by the workflow engine itself, due to the long waiting time and I do not get a status code, what can I do about this to capture this "canceled" event?

@LStrike Can you update your question with a screenshot of this action being "canceled" automatically? Are you sure it is not "timed out"?

To my knowledge, workflows can be cancelled by users manually, but not by the workflow engine itself. Regardless of that, once the workflow is cancelled, that's it - no further actions will be executed. The last paragraph in my answer suggests a possible solution, but it would require a change of design.

I added a part of the log

I don't understand where this screenshot is from. I meant a screenshot of the action that failed, which would show the details of the failure. Anyway, I don't think I can add anything to my answer...

I think my issue is similar to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66888156/condition-action-in-logic-app-shows-as-cancelled-but-evaluates-fine

@LStrike Unfortunately, Tony didn't provide a full screenshot of the Logic App run in this SO question you gave a link to, so not knowing what actions follow his HTTP request it's hard to say what happened there. I've just realized that actions can get status Cancelled when the Terminate action is used in the Logic App - it effectively stops the workflow run, cancels any actions in progress, and skips any remaining actions. Example: https://i.sstatic.net/0TLN6GCY.png Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-actions-triggers#terminate-action

Still, you need to understand that when the workflow is Cancelled - you can't do anything about it, as the processing of this workflow stops there and then. For the rest, I'll redirect you back to my answer above.
